# Show Name Instead of ID from Different Table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a 2 tables:

- `Category` with Primary Key `ID` and column `Name`
- `Employee` with Primary Key `ID` and column `Category_id`

Note: `Category_id` now displays `ID` correctly

I want to show `Name` instead of `ID` for output from `Employee`.

Attempt:

```
$categ = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($categ)) {
  $website_cat = $row;
}
```

`Category` Table:

```
+----+----------------+
| ID | Name           |
+----+----------------+
| 23 | Manager        |
| 10 | Boss           |
| 14 | Worker         |
| 41 | Another        |
+----+----------------+
```

`Employee` Table:

```
+----+----------------+
| ID | Category_id    |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Manager        |
|  2 | Boss           |
|  3 | Worker         |
|  4 | Another        |
+----+----------------+
```

Output:

```
echo $website_cat['category_id'];
```

Comment: I think something in this question is mixed up. Please review and edit it to make it clearer. Perhaps provide an example of the desired output.

Comment: How ID fields of category and employee are related with each other? If they are related then you can use JOIN function of MySQL query to get and display category_id from employee table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SQL keyword you're looking for is `JOIN`.  Your query could be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee INNER JOIN category ON employee.category_id = category.id WHERE id = ...
```

Or, more readably:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  employee
  INNER JOIN category
    ON employee.category_id = category.id
WHERE
  id = ...
```

(Note: I removed that last bit of the `WHERE` clause on purpose because I'm not comfortable putting SQL injection vulnerabilities in an answer.  [Please read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to learn some of the basics of properly executing SQL queries involving user input.  Currently your code is wide open to a very common form of attack.)

Since some of your columns share the same name, you may even want to more explicitly request them:

```
SELECT
  employee.id AS employee_id,
  category.id AS category_id,
  category.name AS category_name
FROM
  employee
  INNER JOIN category
    ON employee.category_id = category.id
WHERE
  id = ...
```

Then in your code you'd have access to these fields:

```
employee_id, category_id, category_name
```

So you could output the value you want:

```
echo $website_cat['category_name'];
```

Comment: yes, this is correct answer, I just need to clarify the issue and to make it display the category for the correct id `WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'`, 
as when I add "where" an error appears **mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource,**. 
_I have read your note regarding 'where'_, 
now I need to find an alternative.

Comment: @TestPRK: That error means the query is failing.  Use `mysql_error()` to get the error message from the database.  The alternative is to use prepared statements with query parameters.  Currently your code is basically executing user input *as code*, so users can execute any code they want on your server.  Prepared statements with query parameters treat user input as *data*, not as *code*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) category table

```
$categ = mysql_query("
SELECT employee.*, category.name as category_name FROM employee 
INNER JOIN category on category.id = employee.category_id
WHERE id = '" . $_GET['id'] . "'");
```

Then output with `$website_cat['category_name']`